# Multiple release messages cause EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, release, nserror

First of all i want to start off by saying I'm kind of a beginner in Objective C and the iPhone world and i'm really loving it so far, its really interesting.

I'm coming from the PHP world and trying to adopt some of the very different concepts of Objective C such as needing to release your own objects to avoid memory leaks.

But i'm having a small issue, when i release more than 1 variable at the end of my function, the app crashes with an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error for some reason. I'm sure its something small and stupid but i'm kinda clueless.

Would appreciate your guidance, here's my code:

```cpp
+ (id) getJsonFromURL: (NSURL *)url withQueryString: (NSString *)queryString withMethod: (NSString *)HTTPMethod error: (NSError **)outError{
    // Initialize request
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[queryString UTF8String] length: [queryString length]];

    // Set request data and method
    [request setHTTPMethod:HTTPMethod];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];

    // Perform request
    NSURLResponse *uResp = nil;
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&uResp error:nil];

    // Make sure HTTP Request was successful (HTTP Code 200)
    NSInteger httpStatus = [((NSHTTPURLResponse *)uResp) statusCode];
    if(httpStatus != 200){
        NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [userInfo setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"The requested URL could not be read (HTTP Code: %d)", httpStatus] forKey: NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
    }[NSException raise:@"MerchGuru.BadURL" format:@"The URL couldn't be read (HTTP Code: %d)", httpStatus];

    // Decode JSON Output
    NSError *jsonError = nil;
    id respData = [[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserialize:returnData error:&jsonError];

    if(jsonError != nil){
        if(outError != nil){
            NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [userInfo setValue:@"The JSON Output provided isn't valid JSON!" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];

            *outError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"com.freak4pc.merchguru" code:6001 userInfo: userInfo];

            [userInfo release];
            NSLog(@"%@", [*outError localizedDescription]);
        }

        [respData release];
        [jsonError release];
        [returnData release];
        [uResp release];
        [requestData release];
        [request release];


        return nil;
    }else{
        [respData release];
        [jsonError release];
        [returnData release];
        [uResp release];
        [requestData release];
        [request release];

        return respData;
    }
}
```

Thank you :)
Shai.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not `release` what you do not own. You only own something if you called `alloc` or `retain` on it. In your example, you should only release `request`

Answer (score 3):

You must only `release` what you've `alloc`ated yourself. Here, you only allocated `request`, so you have to release just `request`. All your other variables are created with convenience methods, so they're autoreleased.

Comment: Thank you! sorry for the noob question :) Appreciate your answer

Comment: By the way , a sort-of related question , are the convenience methods any less better than the manually-allocated ones? Because i could also replace the request to [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; if it doesn't matter.

Comment: Being kind of an old-fashion programmer I always tend to manually alloc/init my objects and release them as soon as I can. Never forget you're developing for a limited platform, at least in terms of available RAM. Just a matter of taste, though; I never liked garbage collectors.

Comment: I understand, but i do wonder if performance-wise or RAM-wise if this manual approach would make a significant change. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I remember a comic book reader I coded last year or so. Every sprintf-like string was coded as NSString *stuff = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %d", a, b]. By running our code with Instruments, memory usage was constantly increasing. As soon as we turned all stringWithFormat into [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:] and releasing them just when they were no longer needed, memory usage stopped increasing and remained stable. [cont...]

Comment: Just my two cents on this, I never took the time to do a full study of which one's better, but I tend to think manual management (drop as soon as it's not needed) is always better than automatic management (drop as soon as I've got nothing better to do)

Answer (score 1):

You can only release objects that you are init'ing.

There are objects in your code that are autoreleased and your EXC_BAD_ACCESS comes from you releasing those objects.

From the code above, it looks like you only need to release the "request" object.